# Disabling tf.function decorators for code coverage pytest run

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

As discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33759), code coverage tools do not work nicely with tensorflow due to its code transformation. One suggested workaround is to use `tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)` when generating reports (though it's worth noting that this still does not handle all cases, e.g. `tf.map_fn`).

**My question is: is there a simple way to do this automatically for tests run using `pytest --cov`?** Is there perhaps something I could add to `conftest.py` that would allow me to make all executions run eagerly whenever I pass a given command line argument, such as `pytest --cov --eagerly`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there perhaps something I could add to conftest.py that would allow me to make all executions run eagerly whenever I pass a given command line argument,

Yes, it turns out:

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser: Parser) -> None:
    parser.addoption(
        "--eager",
        action="store_true",
        default=False,
        help="whether to run all functions eagerly",
    )
    
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config: Config, items: list[pytest.Item]) -> None:
    if config.getoption("--eager"):
        import tensorflow as tf
        tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
```